# New to rigging in Blender 2.49

Tags: modeling

Just recently started with Blender, I am using a very old version : 2.49 , reason is I am trying to create new models for Civilization 4 and the the nif export script work only with 2.49 as far as I know. About my problem, I downloaded this mecha model and after familiarizing myself with the program, I tried to create an armature for the mesh with all the bones.

I then:
1- Selected the mesh
2- Shift pressed on the armature
3- Went to object
4- Parent -> Armature -> Armature attached to bone heat
5- Tried Pose mode to see if everything was working and...

[image]

I was expecting only the rifle to move after selecting the rifle but for some reason , some vertex remain attached to the main body ?!
Can anybody clarify where I went wrong?

Regards

Comment: Are you really sure you want to use this ancient Blender version? Exporting .nif-files should be possible in Blender 2.9 using this (https://github.com/niftools/blender_niftools_addon) addon.

Comment: Apparently the scripts don't work for CIV4 that's why I use an older version of Blender

Comment: Have you tried it yourself? What is the exact problem with the exported files?